# How to cross reference typedef in different class?

Tags: c++

In class A, I have defined a type, namely A_T:

```
typedef int A_T;
```

In class B, I have defined another type, namely B_T:

```
typedef double B_T;
```

What if I have to use B_T in the head file of A and A_T in the head file of B?

In A.hpp, I need to include B.hpp and use B::B_T, so as for B. Then there must be a cross reference, how to solve it?

Comment: Put all your common `typedef`s in a common header and `#include` that where necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are the same type, and they need to remain interopable between classes, then put the typedefs in a header file, and include the header file in both of your class definitions.

```
// Types.h
#pragma once

typedef int A_T;
typedef double B_T;
```